# Titanium Importing a widget inside another widget controller

Tags: titanium, commonjs

In the appcelerator titanium application I am building, there are two widgets

- an imported widget [VectorImage](https://github.com/appcelerator-services/VectorImage)
- a custom widget staticboard, which should rely on VectorImage widget.

But I don't find the right way to import the VectorImage module in my staticboard widget controller (widget.js).

I've tried :

- var VectorImage = require('com.capnajax.vectorimage/widget');
- var VectorImage = require(WPATH('../../com.capnajax.vectorimage/widget'));

and also directly during my widget creation :

```
var image = Alloy.createController('com.capnajax.vectorimage', {
                    svg: WPATH('chess_pieces/'+pieceImage+'.svg'),
                    top: parseInt(y+inset+cellsSize*(7-rank)),
                    left: parseInt(x+inset+cellsSize*file),
                    width: cellsSize,
                    height: cellsSize
                });
$.widget.add(image);
```

Please, also notice that I managed to integrate it in an hard-coded way, in my widget view (index.xml), e.g :

...
<Widget src="com.capnajax.vectorimage" svg="path.svg" />
...

So it's not the VectorImage widget to blame.

What is the correct way to use this widget in my widget.js ?

Notice that [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21525917/how-to-import-a-widget-in-alloy-titanium) does not solve my problem.

Comment: I found the correct path : var VectorImage = require('../../com.capnajax.vectorimage/controllers/widget');

Answer (score 1):

try:
js:

```
Alloy.createWidget('com.capnajax.vectorimage' ,  {
                    svg: WPATH('chess_pieces/'+pieceImage+'.svg'),
                    top: parseInt(y+inset+cellsSize*(7-rank)),
                    left: parseInt(x+inset+cellsSize*file),
                    width: cellsSize,
                    height: cellsSize
                });
```

Comment: Thank you, but I did not manage this way. I get an exception.